# What is a conditional random field?

Tags: machine-learning, natural-language-processing, definitions, probabilistic-graphical-models, conditional-random-field

I new in machine learning, especially in Conditional Random Fields (CRF).

I have read several articles and papers and in there is always associated with HMM and sequences classification. I don't really understand mathematics, especially in the annoying formula. So I can't understand the process. Where I need to start to understand CRFs??

I want to make an information extraction application using CRF Named Entity Recognition (NER).

I got some tutorial for that: https://eli5.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/sklearn_crfsuite.html#training-data

**But** I don't know the proses each step, like training proses, evaluation, and testing

I use this code :

```
  data_frame = eli5.format_as_dataframes(
            eli5.explain_weights_sklearn_crfsuite(self.crf))
```

**Targets**
[image]

**Transition Features**
[image]

How to get that number ?

and 1 more thing makes me confused:

```
crf = sklearn_crfsuite.CRF(
    algorithm='lbfgs',
    c1=0.1,
    c2=0.1,
    max_iterations=20,
    all_possible_transitions=False,
)
```

What is the algorithm `lbfgs`? Is the CRF not an algorithm? Why do I need `lbfgs`? What is exactly a conditional random field?

Comment: I will provide an answer later, but you will have to wait (unless someone provides an answer meanwhile). Anyway, it is ok to be confused when it comes to CRFs, especially if you don't have a solid mathematical background.

Comment: okay, thank you for responding I really appreciate that @nbro

Comment: heyy i still waiting your answer @nbro :(

Comment: Hey! Sorry for having made you wait for a long time without warning you. CRFs involve a lot of concepts. So, a satisfactory will possibly be quite long, which would have required some time. Meanwhile, I couldn't have spent so much time to give this answer. I will try to give you an answer this weekend.

Comment: @nbro Ok, i will waiting your answer :(

Comment: @nbro hey :( i am still waiting